# How to create an array with strings - string, string, Color Clr = Color.Black?

Tags: c#

There is an array.
We loop through the array lines and send to the method.
I need to pass "Color.Black" and other colors to the method.

**Question.**
1. How to make such an array in which you can store "Color Clr"?
2. Or other ways to accomplish the task?

**Code**

```
public string[,] FillArray()
        {           
            Keywords keyw = new Keywords();

            string[,] ar = {   /*Поле - `keywords`  // Поле - `typeMatchCollection` // Поле - `color`*/ 
                                { keyw.Keywords_prop, "keywords", "Blue"}                 
                               , {keyw.Types_prop,    "types",    "DarkCyan" }
                               , {keyw.Comments_prop, "comments", "Green" }
                               // , {keyw.Strings_prop,  "strings",  "Brown" }
                               , {keyw.Strings_prop,  "strings",  Color Clr = Color.Black }
                                };

            return ar;
        }     

 public void Backlight(MatchCollection matchCollection, Color Clr)
        {

            foreach (Match m in matchCollection)
            {
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart = m.Index;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength = m.Length;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Clr;
                // codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Brown;
                // codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 100, 10, 16);
                // codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.FromArgb(color);
            }
        }
```

[image]

---

### Update 1

This update is based on comments from @jdweng -> Use: `object [,] ar`.

I try to use `object [,] ar`
Result.

```
public void General_2()
        {
            object[,] arr;

            arr = FillArray_1();

            int rows = arr.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
            int columns = arr.Length / rows;
            // или так
            // int columns = mas.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {                
                string keywords = arr[i, 1].ToString();
                string typeMatchCollection = arr[i, 2].ToString();
                Color color = arr[i, 3] as Color;

                MatchCollection matchCollection = null;
                matchCollection = CreateCollectionMatchcollection(keywords, typeMatchCollection);

                Backlight_1(matchCollection, color);
            }
        }
```

I have an error in the line `Color color = arr [i, 3] as Color;`

**Update 1. Question.**
1. How to get `Color` from an array?

Comment: Use : object[,] ar

Comment: @jdweng How to get `Color` from an array?
See `Update-1`

Comment: cast the object to a Color.

Comment: @jdweng So? `Color color = (Color)arr[i,3];`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an array, you can use a list of items like that.

Define a class Item and change this name by what you want:

```
public class Item
{
  public string Property { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

Change members names by what you need.

Use it like that:

```
var list = new List<Item>();

list.Add(new Item 
         { 
           Property = keyw.Strings_prop, 
           Description = "strings", 
           Color = Color.Black 
         });
```

Then to pass the color to the method use this:

```
Backlight(collection, list[index].Color);
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to pass the color's name as a string and use the `FromName` method to get the `Color` object on the other side.

...

```
string color = Color.Red.Name; //  set colors name
```

...

```
Color Clr =  Color.FromName(color); // convert color name to Color
```

...